# Duplicate in Object storage

Tags: python, django, hash, object-storage

I use a [Minio-backend](https://pypi.org/project/django-minio-backend/) in the Django app. I have a feature that users can use the object storage(user online gallery), and Also, users can upload a new image from the device to create a post. But when I use the object storage images and create an image, images duplicate in object storage(because each time I create a post, I want to upload new images( images that upload locally) in object storage). What should I do to prevent these duplicates?

It is my model:

```
        class MediaStorage(models.Model):   
                    file = models.FileField(verbose_name="Object Upload",
                                storage=MinioBackend(bucket_name='django-backend-dev-private'),
                                upload_to=iso_date_prefix)
```

this is my create new post :

```
class CreatePostView(generics.CreateAPIView):


 ...
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            user = request.user
            data = request.data
    
            ...
        for media_file in post_files:
            file_team=post_team
            f = MediaStorage.objects.create(team=file_team,owner=user)
            f.media=media_file
            f.save()
            post.multimedia.add(f)

        return Response(post_serializer.PostSerializer(post).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't upload directly,u could get image md5 first,and a attr to `MediaStorage` to save md5 value,before upload check is there same md5 in DB,If has that may you already upload this image before

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You mean I should convert it to hashcode? Do you have any example or piece of code so I can realize How can do this?

Comment: I suggest the best way to do this is let frontend to do the md5,if u want to this fron the backend u need to parsing the image do a lot unnecessary work.Are u still want the solution from the backend?